# RxJava Single: flatMap if false

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I have a list of Boolean Singles that I want to convert to a Maybe in the following way:

Go through each emission from the list in order, if the upstream emission is false `flatMapMaybe` to a `Maybe.never()` but if the emission is true subscribe to the next Single in the list until the list is empty.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void subscribeIfAllTrue(List<Single<Boolean>> singles) {

    if (singles.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Single.concat(blockingSingles)
            .flatMapMaybe(
                    (Function<Boolean, MaybeSource<Boolean>>) shouldProgress -> {
                        if (shouldProgress) {
                            // flatMap to next single in list.
                            // if last in list then Maybe.just(true)
                        } else {
                            Maybe.never();
                            // break from list
                        }
                    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work since we are subscribing to all singles via concat but that is not the behavior I want. Wondering if there was an rx operator to basically `break;` and stop subscribing from list of subscriptions if one emission is false, also when last in last just return `Maybe.just(true)`. Was looking

The main reason I dont want to subscribe to all singles is that the upstream boolean emission is performing a ui change that and if one is false dont want to trigger the ui change for the rest by just breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `takeUntil` (and perhaps, `lastElement()`) for the desired pattern.

```
Mayble<Boolean> m = Single.concat(blockingSingles)
    .takeUntil(bool -> !bool)
    .lastElement()
```